# How to prevent re-rendering of components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I used Redax in the project to change the theme, but when I change the theme, my component render again.(
I have several tabs, each of which is a component. When I have several tabs open and I change the theme, all the components are rendered again. )

What can I do to prevent the components I have from being rendered again?

**app.js**:

```
return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
          <MuiThemeProvider theme={props.theme}>
            <ConfirmProvider>
              <CssBaseline />
              <NotifierProvider>
                <Switch>
                  <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
                  <Route
                    path="/access-denied"
                    render={() => <span>Access Denied</span>}
                  />
                  {!props.user && !offlineMode && <Redirect to="/" />}
                  {props.permissions && (
                      <Layout>
                          <Route path="/main" component={Main} />
                      </Layout>
                  )}
                </Switch>
              </NotifierProvider>
            </ConfirmProvider>
          </MuiThemeProvider>
        </StylesProvider>
      </Suspense>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    theme: state.app.theme,
    user: state.account.user,
    permissions: state.account.permissions,
  };
};
```

**index.js:**

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  app: appReducer,
  account: accountReducer,
});

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

const app = (
  <AppProvider>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </AppProvider>
);

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**header.js:**

```
          const themeChangeHandler = () => {
            if (props.themeName === "darkTheme") props.changeTheme("lightTheme", null);
            else props.changeTheme("darkTheme", null);
          };
    
    
        <Link
                      onClick={() => themeChangeHandler()}
                      className={classes.headerBtn}
                    >
                      {props.themeName === "darkTheme" ? (
                        <SunIcon className={classes.icon} />
                      ) : (
                        <DarkModeIcon className={classes.icon} />
                      )}
                    </Link>
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    themeName: state.app.themeName,
  };
};
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return {
        changeTheme: (themeName, customTheme) =>
          dispatch(actions.changeTheme(themeName, customTheme)),
      };
    };
```

**action->app.js:**

```
export const changeTheme = (themeName, customTheme) => {
  const theme = themeCreator(themeName, customTheme);
  localStorage.setItem("theme", themeName);
  localStorage.setItem("customTheme", JSON.stringify(customTheme));
  return {
    type: actionTypes.THEME_CHANGED,
    themeName,
    customTheme,
    theme,
  };
};
```

Comment: please explain more, I expect a re-render of all my component since the theme changes.

Comment: Shouldn't you wrap main App.js file in `MuiThemeProvider` instead of passing it here?

Comment: a bit of general advice for your code implementaion, separate each provider into a file and then import them in your App.js. Good luck 

Comment: You can use [react memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) to prevent re-render a component when the props are the same

Comment: @novonimo Can you give an example?

Comment: yes sure, create a separated file (.js / .jsx) for each provider. in your case you need these:
1. RouterProvider 2. StylesProvider 3.MultiThemeProvider 4.ConfirmProvider 5.NotifProvider ;
then separate each implementation from the above code into an independent file and export each provider from the file, consider passing the `children` props in providers.
now in your App.js import your providers and wrap them together.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to delay the rerender of components that are not on display for now you can use the `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` which takes the nextProps, and nextState as inputs. if your component knows whether it is showing or not you can make a simple comparison and prevent the rerender.

However, if you need more than that to prevent a rerender, it is probably not worth it since react render is an optimized and fast process.

You can find `shouldComponentUpdate` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate).